# How to use an alias by an executable?

Tags: bash, alias, executable, terraform, ansible-inventory

When running `terraform-inventory` executable, in the background it runs another executable by name `terraform`. I would like it to follow an alias and run `terraformX` instead. Since I want original `terraform` executable to remain unchanged, I added `terraformX`. Therefore I can't create a symlink to `terraformX` and name it `terraform`. `terraformX` is another version of `terraform`.

Alias command:

```
alias terraform='terraformX'
```

You could enable alias expansion for scripts with:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

However, this is not a script, and the executable is not expanding the alias. Is there a way to make it expand the alias?

`terraform-inventory` is an executable from this project: https://github.com/adammck/terraform-inventory.
`terraform` is an executable from this website: https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/index.html

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more what the *executable* is here? and *binary*? is any of your *executable*, *binary* or *command* a shell script?

Comment: Also, exactly how does it "call" the other command?

Comment: Rephrased the question. Provided one method of solving the issue. Still interested in knowing if an executable can use aliases.

Comment: where does this terraformX  point to

Comment: `terraformX` is another version of `terraform`.

Comment: I was not able to use an alias from within an executable and bash manual says: `Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an alias, a temporary modification of PATH environment variable can help. The key is to remove the path of `terraform` executable and put `terraformX` executable in a different location (then `terraformX` can be named `terraform` or a symlink created to it with name `terraform`).

Run:

```
which terraform
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/terraform
```

Run:

```
export PATH=~/:/bin/
mv terraformX ~/terraform
which terraform
```

Output:

```
~/terraform
```

Now running `terraform-inventory --list` will run `terraform state pull` in the background using `~/terraform` instead of `/usr/bin/terraform`.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to modify the source code of `terraform-inventory` and have it execute `terraformX` instead of `terraform`. Then compile source code of `terraform-inventory` into an executable.

Answer (score 0):

its a bit of long shot

do this

expand the alias and take the command say your command is

```
"terraform --print this"
```

now write a program

```
int main( int ac, char **av )
{
   return system( "terraform --print this" ); // or whatever the expanded alias
}
```

compile and give it the same name as your alias, copy it to your PATH

Comment: Thank you. When you mentioned the word PATH, I realized a simple method of solving my problem.